# Changing xp desktop background to default in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a destkop background in xp. I want to run a batch file that will change my current background to the default value of None which is just a solid color. An example would be great if anyone has one.

thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/277805/how-do-i-set-the-desktop-background-on-windows-from-a-script

Answer (score 0):

I ended up abandoning this idea because I didn't need it after I figured out another issue I had, but I did find a good site which I can't remember that gave examples of reading and writing registry keys using vbscript. I was able to have some wallpaper on my desktop and put this vbscript in my startup so that the wallpaper would be reverted back to the 'None' solid color style. It looked like this

```
Option Explicit

Dim SysVarReg, Value, NewValue

Set SysVarReg = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Read current value of desktop wallpaper
value = SysVarReg.RegRead ("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper")

' Display to screen for testing
'MsgBox(value)


NewValue = ""

' Reset the value of the wallpaper to an empty string for the default no wallpaper
SysVarReg.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper", NewValue

' Display to screen again for testing
'MsgBox(NewValue)
```